# Displaying PopUpWindow from an other Class - Android

Tags: android, onclick, popupwindow

Basically, I have two classes :
    - MyActivity.java
    - OtherClass.java

Overview of MyActivity.java : 
Nothing really interesting in there ... except the instanciation of what is need by the otherClass.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    context       = getApplicationContext()                 ;
    main_activity = this                                    ;
    layout        = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    /*
     * Do lot of stuff
     */
}
```

Overview of OtherClasse.java :

It has a clickable TextView. And when I make a LongClick event, I would like to display a PopUpWindow (on the UI-Thread, so MyActivity ...)

```
view.setOnLongClickListener( new OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        Log.d("TAG", "OnLongClick");
        PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(activity.getApplicationContext());
        //tried with new PopupWindow(MyActivity.context);
        popup.setWindowLayoutMode(150, 150);
        popup.setContentView( view );
        //view corresponds to the TextView.
        popup.showAtLocation(MyActivity.layout, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 10, 10);
        return true;
    }
});
```

The log indicate that I entered in the onLongClick() ...
But the application crash ...

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

But MyActivity.layout is a static LinearLayout, so I would be able to add view to it ...
Any suggestion on how to show PopUpWindow from onClickListener of an other Class ?

---

EDIT :

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(BlaActivity.context);
    TextView tv = new TextView(BlaActivity.context);
    LayoutParams para = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tv.setLayoutParams(para);
    tv.setText("My future text ...");
    popup.setContentView(tv);
    popup.setWidth(400);
    popup.setHeight(180);
    popup.showAtLocation(tv, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 10, 10);
    popup.update();

    return true;
}
```

Returns a

android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

Because `popup.showAtLocation(tv, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 10, 10);` Calls to `public IBinder getWindowToken ()` on tv ... Witch doesn't have Token obviously ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view you refer to here

```
popup.setContentView( view );
```

could be the problem. You create a new instance of the pop up window each time but if you are using the same textview each time then that is what would be causing the IllegalStateException.

The following code is simply an activity and a second class. onLongClick creates an instnce of AnotherClass and calls showPopUp.

The constructor of AnotherClass takes in a context as a parameter, which is later used to instantiate the popup.

showPopUp takes in a view which is used as a parent for the popup.

the activity's onCreate

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
        b.setOnLongClickListener( new OnLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    new AnotherClass(getApplicationContext()).showPopUp(parent);
                    return true;
                }
            });
    }
```

a second class

To use a click/touch listener in OtherClass you can declare them as you normally would but   to create a popup inside the listener you need give the context of an activity. Something like this is fine

```
public class AnotherClass {
    Context ctx;
    public AnotherClass(Context ctx){
        this.ctx = ctx;

        //***EXAMPLE*** wont actually be visible as its not added to a view
        Button b2 = new Button(ctx);
        b2.setText("show popup");
        b2.setOnLongClickListener( new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            showPopUp(v);//View v can be used as the parent
            return true;
        }
    });
    }

    public void showPopUp(View parent) {

        PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(ctx);
        TextView tv = new TextView(ctx);
        LayoutParams para = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tv.setLayoutParams(para);
        tv.setText("My future text ...");
        popup.setContentView(tv);
        popup.setWidth(400);
        popup.setHeight(180);
        popup.showAtLocation(parent, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 10, 10);
        popup.update();
    }

}
```

and the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black" android:id="@+id/layout">
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Button" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"></Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what do you suggest then to fix that ?
Even using the view from the onLongClick(View v)
`popup.setContentView( v );` ... I still have the IllegalStateException

Comment: In fact. I just tried to displaysomething on the PopUpWindow ... I also tried with a textView created just before, it doesn't work ... See the code added.

Comment: in your updated code your passing the textview tv as the parent in showAtLocation but tv is already a child of the popup, I'll edit my answer with a piece of code that works for me

Comment: Well ... It Works fine, thanks.
But in fact, it's not really the same architecture. In your code, the MainActivity has the LongClickListener.
But my architecture is the following...
OtherClass contains textView and other attributes that I need. Several instance of OtherClass are created after parsing a document (So, I have 1 OtherClass instance per word defined in the parsed XML document ...)
And then, the MyActivity just display the severals textView of OtherClass instances.

Comment: So is it possible to use the onLongClick in the OtherClass ? and still have the popup window displayed in the UI-Thread ?
Should I define a static LongClickListener in MyActivity, and let textView of OtherClass listen to it ?

Comment: yes it is possible as long as the popup uses the context of the activity that is currently visible in its constructor. I'll edit my answer again to address this issue.

Comment: Last question. Do I really have to create a new instance of AnotherClass on OnLongClick ? Because in fact, they already have been instanced after parsing. So, creating a new instance might not be "safe" for resource-management

Comment: There's no reason why you have to, I was just using this way as a simple example

Comment: Ok. Great. Thanks for your help =)
Cheers from France !